# The order of the keys in json::Object

Tags: rust

Whatever order I use in here

```
let mut tm = TreeMap::new();
tm.insert("aaa".to_string(), "val1".to_json());
tm.insert("zzz".to_string(), "val2".to_json());

//or
// tm.insert("zzz".to_string(), "val2".to_json());
// tm.insert("aaa".to_string(), "val1".to_json());

let a = json::Object(tm);
println!("Json is {}", a)
```

The result json is always the same:

```
json is {"aaa":"val1","zzz":"val2"}
```

But I want the order to be the same as it is in `insert` operations. How?

Comment: A JSON dictionary is not ordered; if you need something ordered, use an array of key/value pairs instead.

Comment: @minitech, I need ordered json.

Comment: That would be a completely new format and [not JSON](http://www.json.org/), then. I would suggest not making it look like JSON if you’re going to invent something, though.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's a very bad idea to rely on order of keys in JSON. Usually the underlying data structure is a hash table, it does not preserve order (the standard does not require it, and a hash map turns out to be the most efficient way of implementing such unordered map). There are some implementations of JSON parsers/generators which preserve order (and some even allow duplicates), but you can never rely on this behavior.

So the best way to achieve the result you want is to use an array of pairs (a pair can be either an array or a map). The order of elements within array is preserved.

Comment: **So the best way to achieve the result you want** how do you know what I want?

Comment: You have written that you want to get the values in the same order you inserted them. At least that's how I interpreted it.If you also want the whole structure to be a single JSON map, that's probably impossible. You may, of course, just create a string which will look like "ordered JSON" by simply concatenating all your keys and values. But any valid JSON parser may reorder them during reading.

Comment: Actually the underlying data structure is a TreeMap, so the keys are sorted.

Comment: I referred to general case, rather than this implementation. So, indeed in rust the keys are sorted. But not in the order of their insertion, of course.

Comment: There is, of course, a significant difference between the terms *sorted* and *ordered*.

Comment: And I also have written that it should be json.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp And `[{"zzz":"val2"},{"aaa":"val1"}]` **would** be JSON, wouldn't it?